# Cleaning or shortening of code

Tags: java

I'm a bit trouble and this has been bugging my mind around for a couple of days, and I can't seem to grasp if there is a possible way to shorten down this (taken from an interface), (Updated):

```
public Pair<Map<Position, Unit>,Map<Position,City>> performAction
             (Position p, Map<Position, Unit> unitMapping, Map<Position,City> cityMapping);
```

It's quite hard to make out because of length, but I'm using this to transfer two hashmaps back from a method call, due to the Strategy pattern (which is mandatory, so can't change the design pattern).

So I have been thinking there might be a shorter way like assign Pair two abstract values like Pair or something. Hints or examples are welcome!

Comment: Step one, stop using generics and maps instead of objects. Get over your object phobia and actually write Java. What is the modelling concept that your two maps represent? Create that object, use that instead.

Comment: Make classes, and wrap them together.  Have a `Mapping` class with a field containing a `Map<Position, Unit>`.  There is not a way to alias types in Java.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by wrapping them together? I'm using Mapping because of the need for iteration in other methods. So, care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the comments suggest is to hold each (or both) maps in their own class:

```
class UnitMapping {
    Map<Position, Unit> mapping;
}

class CityMapping {
    Map<Position, City> mapping;
}
```

and then

```
public Pair<UnitMapping, CityMapping> performAction(Position p,
                                                    UnitMapping unitMapping,
                                                    CityMapping cityMapping);
```

In the case above it makes sense to hold both maps in 1 class because they are coupled, but we don't know the rest of the story.

Comment: Is there any downsides to wrapping, two maps together for instance? I've been jumping a bit back and forth and it is possible to squeeze both into one class.

Comment: @Xsis Putting both maps in one class implies that they have a joint function - whenever one is relevant the other is too (because you use the wrapping object which contains both). It also means that there is the same amount of these maps. It's a matter of design.